# Can't put(show) an image into Android Project

Tags: java, android, image, syntax, imageview

i've just started android programming and i can't put the image into MainActivity.java. I get an error.

Multiple markers at this line

```
 -Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
 FormalParameterList
- Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
 FormalParameterList
- Syntax error on token "setImageResource", Identifier expected after 
 this token
```

Java code is 
(i get an error on 2nd line)

```
.....
      final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
```

Android is

```
   <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  />
```

Help me please, i really can't understand what is that, i've been stucking on it for 2 weeks!

Comment: please show me all code because this is working on my side and also show me all error lines

Answer (score 3):

I guess ic_launcher is not in drawable folder, but in mipmap. So you need to use R.mipmap.ic_launcher in code and @mipmap/ic_launcher in xml

Comment: Oh, it doesn't help ;( But there is progress-only 2 errors has left  'code' Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "setImageResource", Identifier expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error, insert "... VariableDeclaratorId" to complete 
  FormalParameterList 'code'

Comment: And it doesn't matter. because "setImageResource' error have to occur anyway

Answer (score 0):

Why have you declared ImageView variable as `final`? If you declared a variable as **`final`**, **it can never be changed after it has been defined**. So, try to remove `final` keyword of image declaration.

You could also remove `android:src` declaration from your layout, instead of removing `final` keyword.

Comment: Actually, the program is completely wrong, it can't even identify "setImageResource" as a function :(

Comment: Your ic_launcher is a png? Is it in drawable folder?

Comment: Yes, it has a png format. Yes, it is in drawable folder, because in main_activity i don't have any problems.

Comment: This problem is so weird :S Do you have this import? import android.widget.ImageView;

Comment: Yes, i did that. Personally, i think this problem would never be solved

Comment: This problem remembers me another problem I have with Android, concretely with R import. The IDE didn't recognize it until I restart it. But probably this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: No, the problem  with "setImageResource". It looks like Eclipse seems it as "Bla-bla-bla"

Comment: It could be an Eclipse bug (this isn't so strange haha). I don't know. I'm using Android Studio to developing in Android, and never have this problem.